# Magento System Configuration setting not load whole page

Tags: magento-1.9, system-configuration

Im facing one critical issue.

I Install One Extension. its work perfactly in frontend.

but when i open configuration of that extension its load only 2 config section not whole page. as well as footer also not display.

system.xml file is of 29000 line long.

and no any error dipsplay . also i check var/log

is there is any limitation in system.xml file????

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have turned on compilation. Before installing any extension, you need to disabled compilation (System -> Tools -> Compilation)
2. Make sure after copying all the files, clear the store cache, log out the admin panel and login again.

Comment: Compilation is disable already